# MLE of p in Bernoulli(p) where the range is specified

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, bernoulli-distribution

Came across this [image: question] where b is binomial (the distribution is Bernoulli(p)). There's only one sample here, and I found that the MLE of p is X itself (by equating the first derivative to 0). I think I'm missing the indicator function $I=1 \hspace{0.1cm} \textrm{if} \hspace{0.1cm} p \in [\frac{a}{a+b}, \frac{b}{a+b}]$ here. Not sure how to incorporate that into the likelihood function.

Comment: This isn't really a question about the likelihood function: it's merely a matter of checking which of the four options matches the answer you already know.  So, plug in the values $X=0$ and $X=1$ into those four formulas and see which one reproduces your own answer.

Comment: Oh, that way I get C. I thought there was a way to derive this. @whuber

Comment: Yes, you can derive it: but you would have to parameterize the problem and choose an algebraic form for your answer that exactly match the (idiosyncratic) choices made by whoever set the problem.  In short, proceeding in the forward direction would help you with this problem only if you got lucky.  This is an example of skills needed to succeed in tests, not of skills needed for statistics.